# How to print out data keys from firebase with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I've been reading the FB docs and watching some youtube videos/tuts and I'm trying to print out the keys/data I have from my FB database. (I'm learning firebase). My end goal is to display the data on React Native app.

But all I get is

{"_query": {"C": null, "D": null, "collectionGroup": null, "endAt": null, "explicitOrderBy": [[Ne]], "filters": [], "limit": null, "limitType": "F", "path": {"len": 1, "offset": 0, "segments": [Array]}, "startAt": null}, "converter": null, "firestore": {"app": [FirebaseAppImpl], "databaseId": [Dt], "settings": [wc]}, "type": "query"}

and

{"_path": {"len": 1, "offset": 0, "segments": ["users"]}, "_query": {"C": null, "D": null, "collectionGroup": null, "endAt": null, "explicitOrderBy": [], "filters": [], "limit": null, "limitType": "F", "path": {"len": 1, "offset": 0, "segments": [Array]}, "startAt": null}, "converter": null, "firestore": {"app": [FirebaseAppImpl], "databaseId": [Dt], "settings": [wc]}, "type": "collection"}

Here's my code, any advice or help will be much appreciated.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const collectionRef = collection(db,'users');
  const q = query(collectionRef, orderBy('nombre', 'desc'))

  console.log(collectionRef)
  console.log(q)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `query(collectionRef, orderBy('nombre', 'desc'))` you actually define a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.query).

To get the document(s) corresponding to this query you need to use the **asynchronous** [`getDocs()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#getdocs) method, as follows:

```
import { collection, query, orderBy, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const q = query(collectionRef, orderBy('nombre', 'desc'));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

---

Same code with [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

```
const q = query(collectionRef, orderBy('nombre', 'desc'));

getDocs(q).
then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

Comment: It gives me the "Unexpected reserved word 'await'."

Comment: This is because you need to include this code in an `async` function, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function. The other possibility is to use `then()`: I'll adapt the answer to include this version. In any case, as emphasized in my answer, most of the Firebase methods are **asynchronous** and return Promises: [you have to integrate this aspect in your code](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-asynchronous-javascript/).

Comment: That worked, I thank you from the bottom of my heart my dear friend.